# How to get all properties name from groovy template

Tags: java, templates, dynamic, groovy

I use Groovy template from java code:

```
import groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine

String template = 'Hello, $firstname <%print lastname%>!';

Map vars = new HashMap<String, String>();
vars.put("firstname", "John");
vars.put("lastname", "Doe");

SimpleTemplateEngine engine = new SimpleTemplateEngine();
Writable w = engine.createTemplate(template).make(vars);

System.out.println(w.toString());
```

How to get list off all properties name from this template, e.g.:

- firstname
- lastname

?

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible.

Comment: only regular expression?

Comment: Unfortunately I think so. API doesn't seem to support such listing. Why You need it? Can You describe the scenario?

Comment: As I stated in the comment it seems impossible. See [this][1] post.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16971856/how-to-get-the-list-of-variables-used-on-a-groovy-template

Comment: Users (with admin options) make own templates for application and describe some variables (author, date, name etc).
Then application request from simple user values of this properties and received result.

Comment: So it seems that the only option is regex or users will list the values by themselves + validation.